# shuffling cards with Javascript and inconsistent array values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, race-condition

I'm building a little module in javascript to act like a pack of cards. My first method works but was quite simple, and so i wanted to create some shuffle methods that mimic the idea behind real world card shuffling.

Amongst some other useful functions I've create riffle, overhand and cut functions, that all seem to do there job, but when calling them repeatedly in sequence the returned pack amount is inconsistent, from running it over and over again it appears to be some sort of race condition, but  can't seem to get my head around how to avoid it.

The relevant private methods are :

```
riffle : function riffle() {
        var top         = Pack.slice(0, 26);
        var bottom = Pack.slice(26, 52);
        Pack = [];
        console.log('top is '+top.length+" and bottom is "+bottom.length);
        var hand    = 'right';
        var result = [];
        var i = 52;

        while (i > 0) {
            var drop    = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;
            var cards;



            if (hand === 'right' ) {
                if (drop >= top.length) {
                    cards = top;
                } else {
                    cards = top.splice(0, drop);
                }
                hand = 'left';

            } else {
                if (drop >= bottom.length) {
                    cards = bottom;
                } else {
                    cards = bottom.splice(0, drop);
                }
                hand = 'right';
            }

            result = result.concat(cards);
            i -= drop;

        }
        Pack = result;
        console.log(Pack.length+" after riffle");
        return this;
    },

 cut : function cut(fn) {
        var top         = Pack.slice(0, 26);
        var bottom = Pack.slice(26, 52);
        Pack = [];
        console.log(top);
        Pack = bottom.concat(top);
        console.log(Pack.length+" after cut");
        if (fn && typeof(fn) === 'function') { fn(); }
        return this;
    }
```

Later on I have a privileged method called shuffle that calls them :

```
    shuffle   : function shuffle(cb) {
        State.cardsOut = [];
        Internal.generatePack().cut().riffle().riffle()
                            .riffle().riffle().riffle();

        if (cb && typeof(cb) === 'function') { cb(); }
    }
```

Note : I start with a generate function that creates an arrray of objects representing a full pack of 52 cards.  The results I get when I console log the pack at different times after shuffles and cuts vary and I can't seem to figure out why.

you can see what i'km working on here

https://gist.github.com/Pushplaybang/66bc7a1fa5d84eee2236

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: I understand the motivation, but there's [mathematical theory](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/05/28/the-intuition-behind-fisher-yates-shuffling/) behind true random shuffling.

Comment: Not an answer on your question but when i look at your gist i see a weird syntax error i think.
line 104: var drop z = Math.floor(Math.random()*9)+1;

Comment: you decrement `i` by the value in `drop` but `drop` maybe higher than the number of actual cards spliced. In your `drop>=top.length` (and bottom) block you should set drop to top.length (or bottom.length). Or test the lengths of top and bottom ie `while(top.length && bottom.length)`

Comment: @Pointy sure,- and thanks for the link - i get that but i'm building this more to play with JS than the math, and want to create an approximate model of real shuffling techniques.

Comment: You never refill the `Pack` array after emptying it in the `riffle` function.

Comment: sorry that was some bad copy paste, sorted @MT0

Comment: @PatrickEvans I'm not sure i understand you, the drop variable needs to be set randomly in order simulate 1, 2 or three cards being dropped in the riffle by either hand,

Comment: A simpler version of riffle: `var l = 0, r = 26, cards = [];
while ( l < 26 || r < 52 ){
 var ll = Math.min( 26 - l, Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 ) + 1 );
 for ( var i = 0; i < ll; i++ )
  cards.push( Pack[l++] );
 var rr = Math.min( 52 - r, Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 ) + 1 );
 for ( var i = 0; i < rr; i++ )
  cards.push( Pack[r++] );
}
Pack = cards;`

Comment: Ok say, i = 4, top.length = 3, bottom.length = 1, and hand = "right".  drop gets a random value of 5. Since 5 > 3, you just set cards to top, and then do i-=drop (so 4 - 5). i<0 so your while loop ends, but your bottom array still has 1 card in it.

Comment: thanks patrick got you and got it sorted, really wasn't thinking there, wanna add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `drop` variable stores the number of cards you are supposed to be riffling from either the left or right hand. However, there are two instances:

```
if (drop >= top.length) {
    cards = top;
}
```

and

```
if (drop >= bottom.length) {
    cards = bottom;
}
```

where `drop` can be greater than the number of remaining cards in the half of the pack so more cards will be subtracted from `i` than you have actually riffled. You can fix this by:

```
if (drop >= top.length) {
    drop  = top.length;
    cards = top;
    top   = [];
}
```

and

```
if (drop >= bottom.length) {
    drop   = top.length;
    cards  = bottom;
    bottom = [];
}
```

(You need to empty the arrays or you may end up adding the same cards twice).

**Other issues**

- You have magic numbers in the code (`26` and `52`) these could be constants defined in the class and given appropriate names (i.e. `PACK_SIZE = 52`) which would mean that if you create a sub-class representing a different number of cards then it would still work.
- `hand` has two possible values which could be represented as a boolean but you assign it strings (again you could use constants `LEFT_HAND = true, RIGHT_HAND = !LEFT_HAND`).
- `Pack` appears to be a global variable - I would have thought it ought to be a member of the class.
- You do not need to name the functions as this is just polluting the global namespace: `riffle : function riffle() {` can just be an anonymous function `riffle : function() {`.
- Performance - you create additional arrays with each iteration and the cards are moved multiple times. This could be more efficient.

Something like this:

```
PACK_SIZE: 52,
riffle : function() {
  var index_of_cards_riffled_from_top = 0;
  var index_of_cards_riffled_from_bottom = this.PACK_SIZE / 2;
  var riffled_cards = [];
  while ( index_of_cards_riffled_from_top < this.PACK_SIZE / 2
         || index_of_cards_riffled_from_bottom < this.PACK_SIZE ) {
    var num_cards_to_riffle_top = Math.min( this.PACK_SIZE / 2 - index_of_cards_riffled_from_top, Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 ) + 1 );
    var num_cards_to_riffle_bottom = Math.min( this.PACK_SIZE - index_of_cards_riffled_from_bottom, Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 ) + 1 );
    while ( num_cards_to_riffle_top > 0 ) {
      riffled_cards.push( this.Pack[ index_of_cards_riffled_from_top++ ] );
      num_cards_to_riffle_top--;
    }
    while ( num_cards_to_riffle_bottom > 0 ) {
      riffled_cards.push( this.Pack[ index_of_cards_riffled_from_bottom++ ] );
      num_cards_to_riffle_bottom--;
    }
  }
  this.Pack = riffled_cards;
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer thank you, and I am absolutely working through it to make this more dynamic as you've suggested.  I'm also starting to add randomness to the cut positions for my cut method and for the riffle cut.  Making the pack size variable as well is also essential as I'd like the option of excluding cards or including jokers for certain games.

Comment: Note that the actual problem was not emptying the top and bottom arrays when they were lower than or equal to the drop amount.  But the other information was also insightful.

Answer (score 0):

while @MTO 's answer did solve my problem, I'd like to shed some light on how I've chosen to begin refactoring this function.

```
    riffle : function riffle() {
        var cutPos = Math.floor(Math.random()*rv)+( (cardCount-rv) / 2 );
        var splitPack = {
            left : Pack.splice(0, cutPos),
            right : Pack.splice(0, Pack.length)
        };

        var hand    = 'right',result = [], i = 52, cards;

        while(i > 0) {
            drop    = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;

            if (drop >= splitPack[ hand ].length) {
                drop = splitPack[ hand ].length;
            } 

            cards = splitPack[ hand ].splice(0, drop);
            hand = (hand === 'left') ? 'right' : 'left';

            result = result.concat(cards);
            cards = [];
            i -= drop;

        }

        Pack = result;
        console.log(Pack.length+" after riffle");
        return this;
    },
```

a few things :

- the elements that seem global are not really, as this is all wrapped within a function that creates a new "deck" object, and some elements need to be private, such as the cards remaining in the pack once dealing has begin.
- While booleans would work well for the hands, I wanted to boil this down somewhat and so use the strings to select obj properties.
- everything MTO said about using constants is absolutely valid.
- by now splicing each time, we're removing the elements from the array.
- I prefer this approach as it only uses one while loop.
- lastly, this type of shuffle is meant to emulate hand shuffling, and must be combined with other hand shuffling methods, ideally in a repetitive sequence, to produce something useful,
- if you want something consistently random and efficient use fischer-yates algorithm.